# UIButton image offset in iOS 12

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell, ios12

I've got an app in which works as expected in iOS 11, but in iOS 12 some of the images are offset strangely and I've been unable to figure out the reason. The `UIButton` is embedded in a `UICollectionViewCell` in a `UICollectionVIew`. The code to set the images is

```
let fm = FileManager.default
var imgName = "missingImage"

if fm.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
    imgName = url.path
}
let thumbImg = UIImage(named: imgName)
playVideoButton.setImage(thumbImg, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

The first image is a missingImage.png file I created in Photoshop and it works exactly as expected. The other images are all downloaded and saved in the Documents directory. Initially I thought that might be the cause, but when I dropped one of those images into the app bundle and used it instead of the `missingImage` resource, I had the same offset problem. All the images are flattened PNG files, but I don't see why image format would be the cause. All images are the same size.

In the screenshot below you'll see the issue. There are 4 cells visible in the collection. The cell itself has a pink background, the button has a white background and I turned off cropping so you can see how image is offset to the left off the side of both the cell and the button.
[image]